# $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n5^n}$ derivatives and intervals of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

My math professor is knee-deep in questions from me and many students as he said, it might have to do with him not writing our homework questions **(no Taylor series or Maclaurin yet):**

I have to find the intervals of convergence for several derivatives of: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n5^n}$$ first off, I can see that $r=x-5$ so $\lvert x-5\rvert\lt1$ giving the interval $(4,6)$ so all I have to do is check the endpoints from here.

I started getting derivatives, I find that $$f^{'}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n(x-5)^n}{n5^n}$$

= $$f^{'}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{5^n}$$ notice my lower limit for the sum, it's still $1$, nor did I decrease the power on $x$ because it seems to make sense. I know that if the lower limit was $n=0$, then we can bump it up to $1$, and differentiate as if there wasn't a sum involved (as in I *would* decrease the power on $x$)

Mostly I'm confused on how derivatives of series work, especially with respect to what $n$ will equal

**Assuming my $f^{'}$ is correct**, I test the endpoints of my hypothetical interval of convergence and clearly find that both when $x=4$ and $x=6$, the series converges, so I get the interval: $[4,6]$ for $f^{'}$ which happens to be wrong:
When $x=4$:  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^n}{5^n}$$
Ignoring the alternating parts (the $(-1)^n$'s), we get that $b_n=\frac{1}{5^n}$ converges to zero, and $b_n$ also decreases, so it **converges** by the alternating series test, the same goes for if:

When $x=6$: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1)^n}{5^n}$$
I don't know if it has to do with me differentiating or something else, but the answer is not $[4,6]$ for $f^{'}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative is incorrect, and I think it's because you're skipping steps. It's not uncommon, when differentiating power series, to re-index the sum so that an $x^n$ appears instead of an $x^{n-1}$, but I think you should write these steps more explicitly.

We have
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n5^n}.$$
Taking the derivative, we take the derivative of each term:
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n(x-5)^{n-1}}{n5^n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^{n-1}}{5^n}.
\end{align*}
Making the substitution $m = n - 1$, or $n = m + 1$, we get
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+2}(x-5)^m}{5^{m+1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{5}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m(x-5)^m}{5^m}.
\end{align*}

You've also made an error, somehow, in your calculation of the radius of convergence: it should be $5$, not $1$. Note that, if $a_n$ is the $n$th term of the sum, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(x-5)^{n+1}}{(n+1)5^{n+1}} \div \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n5^n} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(x-5)^{n+1} \times n 5^n}{(n+1)5^{n+1} (-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n} \\
&= \frac{-n(x - 5)}{5(n + 1)} = -\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot (x - 5).
\end{align*}
So, $|a_{n+1} / a_n| \to \frac{1}{5}|x - 5|$, which is less than $1$ if and only if $|x - 5| < 5$.

A similar calculation reveals $f'(x)$ has the same radius of convergence (indeed, the radius of convergence of the derivative is always the same as the original function). Give it another try with this in mind.

Comment: This accounts for (I hope) every mistake I've been making lately. That m substitution makes sense, it's always the same right ($m=n-1$)? That's one of those things my professor never showed us, he mentioned "other problems" that are in our textbook (which the HW problems come from), but said we wouldn't be working with all "those cases"

Comment: Yep. If the original series is indexed by an $x^n$ term, then differentiation always leave an $x^{n - 1}$ term, which is (often) best reindexed by $m = n - 1$ back to an $x^n$ term.